# youtube video on facebook

Tags: facebook, video, youtube, preview

When I share a link to any Youtube video the video is not loaded to the chronicle and only the link appears in the post as shown in the first link hereafter. In comparison links to vimeo video work well as shown in the second link hereafter. Could you tell why this happens with the links to Youtube video?

https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/602987_10200981706798791_1321606490_n.jpg

https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/998556_10200981706998796_1641522632_n.jpg

Comment: Please keep your questions in english.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your page, or restart the browser. Sometimes it deosn't show the preview.